# Best way to create "free economy shipping" option WITH conditions?

Tags: checkout, magento-1, shipping, free-shipping

Right now we have a shopping cart price rule enabled to give free shipping to orders over $199, in the US excluding Alaska and Hawaii and excluding certain SKUs. This is what's currently implemented: [Wayback Machine Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160320100901/http://addoa.com/blog/how-restrict-free-shipping-magento).

Our only shipping carrier enabled is UPS and we have the free shipping defaulting to UPS Ground.

What I'd like to do is create a shipping option called "Free Economy Shipping" and have that be the free option while UPS Ground shows the regular calculated price.

It looks like to do this I'll need to create a custom shipping module. Would that be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: what is means by  :UPS Ground shows the regular calculated price"?

Comment: Hm, for example if someone had $230 subtotal in their cart we would want shipping to look like this:

Free Economy Shipping - $0
UPS Ground - $12
UPS Two Day Air - $40
UPS Next Day Air - $90

So instead of UPS Ground being the default free shipping option, I want it to default to "Free Economy Shipping."

Comment: In other words you want all UPS options be paid and you need a new separate method, called "Free Economy Shipping" that will be shown for orders over $199 (and some other conditions) and it should be free. Is it true? Do you need a code hack or a shipping restriction module link?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this with Free Shipping carrier in Magento, no module is required. Enable Free Shipping Carrier, set the price really high (20,000). What will happen is that normally it will not show.  But if a promotion rule allows the cart to ship free then free shipping will populate.

The downside of this approach is that it will only show if the whole cart is free shipping, so if say they had just some items it applied to then it wouldn't show up. The only way around that is via doing as you are now and applying it to UPS Ground.